# Multiline logstash "next" not grouping

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, multiline

Short:
I am having troubles with multiline. I get the tag "multiline" on the log but it doesn't put them together.

Explanation:
Logs I receive

```
September 22nd 2016, 13:43:52.738   [0m[[31merror[0m] [0mTotal time: 368 s, completed 2016-09-22 13:43:52[0m
September 22nd 2016, 13:43:51.738   [0m[[0minfo[0m] [0m[36mSuites: completed 29, aborted 0[0m[0m
September 22nd 2016, 13:43:51.738   [0m[[31merror[0m] [0mFailed: Total 100, 
Failed 4, Errors 0, Passed 96[0m
September 22nd 2016, 13:43:51.737   [0m[[0minfo[0m] [0m[36mRun completed in 1 minute, 24 seconds.[0m[0m
September 22nd 2016, 13:43:51.737   [0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mScalaTest[0m
```

The line with "**Total time: %{NUMBER} s**" is repeated multiple time and I'm only interested in these Total time coming after a "**Total, Failed, Error**" line.
Between the first and the second line could be none or several logs.

My configuration is:

```
  grok {
#1
    match => {"message" => "\[.m\[\u001b\[3.m%{NOTSPACE:level}\u001b\[0m\] \u001b\[0m%{NOTSPACE:Status}: Total %{NUMBER}, Failed %{NUMBER}, Errors %{NUMBER}$
    add_tag => [ "test.continue" ]
    tag_on_failure => []
  }
#2
    if "test.continue" in [tags]{
    multiline {
      pattern => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\u001b\[0m$"
      what => "next"
      negate => true
    }
  }
#3
  #OverallTime
  grok {
    match => {"message" => "\[.m\[\u001b\[3.m%{NOTSPACE:level}\u001b\[0m\] \u001b\[0mTotal time: %{NUMBER:Seconds:int} s, completed"}
    add_tag => [ "test.overalltime" ]
    tag_on_failure => []
  }
```

What I get is:

```
beats_input_codec_plain_applied, test.continue, multiline   [0m[[31merror[0m] [0mFailed: Total 100, Failed 4, Errors 0, Passed 96[0m
```

The first log gets the multiline tag and the test.continue but doesn't behave as I expect.

The logic as I understand it is:

1. If you find `[0m[[31merror[0m] [0mFailed: Total 100, Failed 4, Errors 0, Passed 96[0m` then put a tag "test.continue",
2. Multiline every log with the tag "test.continue" and send it to the next line  you find until you find a log with the end `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\u001b\[0m$`
3. Extract the time from that log

More explanation:

I'm believing the behaviour will be,  but is not happening.

1 finding the trigger
    [0m[[31merror[0m] [0mFailed: Total 100, 
    Failed 4, Errors 0, Passed 96[0m

2 Once it finds it, it will take it and added at the beginning of the next line. Since the first part of the log will still match, it will add again the tag and then sends it to the multiline again
    [0m[[31merror[0m] [0mFailed: Total 100, 
    Failed 4, Errors 0, Passed 96[0m [0m[[0minfo[0m] [0m[36mSuites: completed 29, aborted 0[0m[0m

3 It will have the first, second, ... , until it finds the log which finishes with a timestamp and breaks the multiline. The next log will be not added with the tag.

```
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0mFailed: Total 100, Failed 4, Errors 0, Passed 96[0m [0m[[0minfo[0m] [0m[36mSuites: completed 29, aborted 0[0m[0m [0m[[31merror[0m] [0mTotal time: 368 s, completed 2016-09-22 13:43:52[0m
```

Comment: what version of logstash are you running? have you looked at the multiline codec instead of the multiline filter?

Comment: Maybe the multiline filter only joins the logs that pass through it. Since only the logs with "test.continue" go through this filter, they can't join this logs with other lines (but it's a series of guess, so it can be wrong).

Comment: Version 2.4.0 and yes only the test.continue tags are going through the multiline. They get that tag when the previous grok find the "Total 100, Failed 4, etc..." log and the multiline join this line with the next one. So the next line I expected to contain the previous "Total 100, Failed 4..." plus the new information so it will get the tag again because of the first part... Isn't?

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, but shouldn't the first grok have a break_on_match = false. As you want it to carry the data through and do something more with the line? It may just be my tiredness mind!